# NodeJs installed but cant execute it. Messed it up with bash script

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, shell

I'm learning bash scripting and was trying to write a script that checks if nodeJs is installed, and if it is not, then install it.

NodeJs is installed in my system. Before messing it up, the output I got when executing `node -v` was v4.x.x.

Then, I was following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script) and I wrote the following code in my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ command -v node >/usr/bin/node 2>&1 ]; then
    # save node version in a string variable.
    STRING=cat | node -v

    echo "NodeJs version: " ${STRING}
else
    echo "NodeJs not found."
fi
```

I executed my script (testScript.sh) but now when I run `node -v` the output I get is:

```
/usr/bin/node: line 1: ./testScript.sh:: No such file or directory
```

I cant figure out what I broke... any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, you are trying to redirect the output of `command -v node` to the file `/usr/bin/node`. That's not what you want. The script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ command -v node >/dev/null 2>&1 ]; then
    # save node version in a string variable.
    STRING=cat | node -v

    echo "NodeJs version: " ${STRING}
else
    echo "NodeJs not found."
fi
```

Read more about `/dev/null` here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/null.4.html

It seems you have already overwritten the binary file `/usr/bin/node` with the content of the command `command -v node`. Look at the output for the command: `file /usr/bin/node`. It should be an `ELF` file. If you have `ASCII text` in the output, then you have indeed replaced the binary.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Now I modified the script and ran it. But I still can't run `node -v`. It keeps giving me the same strange output. Did I modified something when running the wrong version of the script? (the one with /usr/bin/node). Thanks!

Comment: @PablitooMenii Yes, you did. You will have to reinstall node.

Comment: @PablitooMenii: Yes, you did modify something. You deleted the node executable and replaced it with the output from your script. That's what `command -v node >/usr/bin/node` means.

Comment: @PablitooMenii: Be very careful of the `>` operator. `> somefile` means delete the contents of somefile and write this output to it.

Comment: Got it, Thanks to both of you!